# How to deal with non-config files in /etc in dh_installdeb

Tags: debian, packaging, apt

What is the proper way to handle non-config files located in `/etc` of a Debian package?

**Background:** I'm trying to create a .deb that installs a new repository. Therefore it needs to create a file `/etc/sources.list.d/myrepo.list` on the target machine. However, any files listed in the metadata (i.e. `debian/install`) of the package located in `/etc` are automatically considered to be a config file and will not be removed through `apt-get remove`. The files I put into `/etc` are not intended to be edited by the user and thus I wouldn't consider them config files.

I can't just add a `postrm` script to remove them because then a subsequent install will fail (because it thinks the file is still at its original place).

How can I instruct the packaging mechanism to not consider them config files?

Answer (score 0):

The [Debian New Maintainers' Guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#conffiles)
addresses this point. Extract:

> If the program you're packaging requires every user to modify the
>   configuration files in the /etc directory, there are two popular ways
>   to arrange for them to not be conffiles, keeping dpkg quiet:
>
> Create a symlink under the /etc directory pointing to a file under the
>   /var directory generated by the maintainer scripts.
>
> Create a file generated by the maintainer scripts under the /etc
>   directory.

I'd say generating this file via a script would be a reasonable way to go, myself.